# insert time into php form and submit to mysql

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms

I know this may be easier than it sounds, but ive been searching online for a solution for hours. I want to add a simple html text box to a form where the user can input "arrival time" and submit to mysql. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Show us what you have currently.

Comment: sorry will post this now

Comment: This might help: http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/PHP-MySQL-Creating-Form-Insert-Data-P280.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have the text box validated to a known form, example:

```
2007-06-05 15:26:0
```

parse that submitted and validated value to a PHP date object using strtotime() like so:

```
 $timestamp = strtotime($_POST['userinput']);
 $mysql_date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", $timestamp);
```

Documentation for strtotime: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Then just put the $mysql_date variable into the DB in a datetime column.

Edit: add code for how to validate a value to mysql time string

```
function TimeIsValid(){
    var field = document.getElementById('timeid');
    if(field.value.match("/^([0-9]{2,4})-([0-1][0-9])-([0-3][0-9]) (?:([0-2][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9]))?$/")) 
        return true;
}
```

I'm not sure how good that regex is, I didn't write it, grabbed it from: http://www.dzone.com/snippets/regular-expression-match

Comment: could you give me an example of validating a html text box into the format you described above, right now all i have is a simple text box but I want the user to know to insert hours/minutes/seconds

Comment: I updated the example to be something that would actually work in strtotime() function

Comment: How would the text box be formatted thought? I understand the php date object

Comment: I'll write you up some validation to match that, one second.

Comment: I would consider finding a better regex, that one is not perfect. It will allow you to put a 29th hour in =/

Comment: I am very confused. I dont want the user to select a time, rather enter an arrival time manually into a form which submits to mysql

Comment: right. You have a field that is arrival time. That has the format I specified in the first code block. The javascript validates that the users entry is valid. THen, you submit that value to the server and it writes it into the DB in the correct mysql format.

Comment: is there another option to do this without using Javascript? I'm trying to avoid that

Comment: You should have validation in both places, server and client. If the server validation fails, you can send a message back to the client that says the time format they put in was not valid. To be honest though, javascript warnings are much friendlier to your clients.

Comment: I dont have much experience with javascript so this is going to be a lot more difficult than anticipated.

Comment: I found an easier solution but thankyou for your answers, they were very helpful